# when condition does not match with "ansible_host" Ansible 2.10?

Tags: ansible

I try something very simple but it does not work:

I want to execute a task only, if two strings are the same:

hostname=1-Europe-ECV-Site2
ansible_host=1-Europe-ECV-Site2

This is the playbook:

```
- debug: var=hostname
- debug: var=ansible_host

- name: Gather a virtual machine info
  vmware_guest_info:
    hostname: '{{ vsphere_host }}'
    username: '{{ vsphere_user }}'
    password: '{{ vsphere_password }}'
    validate_certs: false
    datacenter: "{{ vsphere_datacenter }}"
    name: "{{ hostname }}"
    schema: vsphere
    properties:
      - guest.ipAddress
  retries: 60
  delay: 10
  until: gather_vm_info.instance.guest.ipAddress is not none
  register: gather_vm_info
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: ansible_host == hostname
```

I got this result, even if I can see by debugging, that both values are equal:

```
PLAY [Configure vyOS BGP LAN Router] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [get_ip_vsphere : debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [1-Europe-ECV-Site2] => 
  hostname: 1-Europe-ECV-Site2
ok: [1-Europe-ECV-Site3] => 
  hostname: 1-Europe-ECV-Site3
ok: [1-Europe-ECV-Site1-1] => 
  hostname: 1-Europe-ECV-Site1-1
ok: [1-Europe-ECV-Site1-2] => 
  hostname: 1-Europe-ECV-Site1-2

TASK [get_ip_vsphere : debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [1-Europe-ECV-Site2] => 
  ansible_host: 1-Europe-ECV-Site2
ok: [1-Europe-ECV-Site3] => 
  ansible_host: 1-Europe-ECV-Site3
ok: [1-Europe-ECV-Site1-1] => 
  ansible_host: 1-Europe-ECV-Site1-1
ok: [1-Europe-ECV-Site1-2] => 
  ansible_host: 1-Europe-ECV-Site1-2

TASK [get_ip_vsphere : Gather a virtual machine info] ************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [1-Europe-ECV-Site2]
skipping: [1-Europe-ECV-Site3]
skipping: [1-Europe-ECV-Site1-1]
skipping: [1-Europe-ECV-Site1-2]

TASK [get_ip_vsphere : Gather a virtual machine info] ************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [1-Europe-ECV-Site2]
skipping: [1-Europe-ECV-Site3]
skipping: [1-Europe-ECV-Site1-1]
skipping: [1-Europe-ECV-Site1-2]
```

Question:
Why this condition does not match? Do I need to do something special if I want to use the build in variable **ansible_host** I use Ansible 2.10

EDIT:

The purpose of this playbook is to write only the discovered IP address into the inventory YAML file under host_vars, if it is not already defined. As you can see in my example, the ansible_host is equal to the hostname of the VM, if no IP address was detected.

For this I have to check if **ansible_host == hostname** and only then IP must be fetched and written into the YAML inventory file.

Another solution is to check if 192.168. is not included in "ansbile_host" and then execute the task:

```
when: "'192.168' in ansible_host"
```

But this also does not work!

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works, I don't know why the other conditions does not fit:

```
---
- name: Gather a virtual machine info
  vmware_guest_info:
    hostname: '{{ vsphere_host }}'
    username: '{{ vsphere_user }}'
    password: '{{ vsphere_password }}'
    validate_certs: false
    datacenter: "{{ vsphere_datacenter }}"
    name: "{{ hostname }}"
    schema: vsphere
    properties:
      - guest.ipAddress
  retries: 60
  delay: 10
  until: gather_vm_info.instance.guest.ipAddress is not none
  register: gather_vm_info
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: "'192.168' not in ansible_host"


- name: Gather a virtual machine info
  vmware_guest_info:
    hostname: '{{ vsphere_host }}'
    username: '{{ vsphere_user }}'
    password: '{{ vsphere_password }}'
    validate_certs: false
    datacenter: "{{ vsphere_datacenter }}"
    name: "{{ hostname }}"
    schema: vsphere
    properties:
      - guest.ipAddress
  retries: 60
  delay: 10
  until: gather_vm_info.instance.guest.ipAddress != "0.0.0.0"
  register: gather_vm_info
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: "'192.168' not in ansible_host" 


- debug: var=gather_vm_info.instance.guest.ipAddress


- name: Update IP
  block:
    - name: Add ansible_host IP to the YAML inventory file
      delegate_to: localhost
      lineinfile:
        path: host_vars/{{ hostname }}.yml
        line: "  ansible_host: {{ gather_vm_info.instance.guest.ipAddress }}"

    - name: Update dynamic ansible_host with new IP Address
      set_fact: 
        ansible_host: "{{ gather_vm_info.instance.guest.ipAddress }}"
        ansible_hostname: "{{ hostname }}"

  when: "'192.168' not in ansible_host"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think issue is with the `ansible_host` variable. It is because you are trying to match `hostname` with `ansible_host`, which should ideally match every time (looking at the `debug` output).

For example, when the task `vmware_guest_info` runs on `1-Europe-ECV-Site3`:

```
hostname == ansible_host
```

Will be:

```yaml
"1-Europe-ECV-Site3" == "1-Europe-ECV-Site3"
#=> True
```

Which is not what you want, even if it runs. If you want the task to run only when `ansible_hostname` matches `1-Europe-ECV-Site2`, then the condition should be:

```yaml
- name: Gather a virtual machine info
  vmware_guest_info:
    hostname: '{{ vsphere_host }}'
    username: '{{ vsphere_user }}'
    password: '{{ vsphere_password }}'
    validate_certs: false
    datacenter: "{{ vsphere_datacenter }}"
    name: "{{ hostname }}"
    schema: vsphere
    properties:
      - guest.ipAddress
  retries: 60
  delay: 10
  until: gather_vm_info.instance.guest.ipAddress is not none
  register: gather_vm_info
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: ansible_hostname == "1-Europe-ECV-Site2"
```

Comment: I tried this several times, it does not work, even if you "hardcode" the hostname. I have edited my original question, for clarification. Pleas have a look above and thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use IP address in `when` condition, it works. Hostname resolution did not happen in my case.

`when: ansible_host == "xx.xx.xx.xx"`